# Issue after upgrading android Studio and JAVA on MAC OC 10.9

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After upgrading Android studio to 2.0 preview 4 , I am unable to build my existing application . It is givivng following errors :

```
1/ In android studio Preferences it is still showing JRE version 1.6, Although i have updated Java as well
2/ Execution failed for task ':docSink:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'., for this i have enabled MultiDex in my build.gradle file, still having issue.
3/  com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
```

Kindly suggest , if any one has faced this issue. I am stuck in this issue from last two days.

Comment: try invalidate cache restart

Comment: From where we can find this option. Can you please tell me steps ?

Comment: FIle->Invalidate cache & restart

Comment: Still it's not working. Thanks !!

Comment: do one thing close project and re-import project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what I did when I face this error first time

Application specific

> build.gradle

```
   android {

           defaultConfig {
                multiDexEnabled true
           }


           dexOptions {
                incremental true
                javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
           }

   }
```

> Application Class

```
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(base);
    }
```

Don't forget to do clean build project after this configuration changes.

Comment: It is also working fine for me , but many times I tried to run an application getting TargetInvocationExcetion. How to fix this? Also, it is unable to find my Application class , so giving java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: @Preet can you please post a question with details of issue  with required configuration and when you are facing?

Comment: What configuration you want from my side? When I create new project and run it works fine. But when i try to run my old project then it is throwing exception . TargetInvocation Exception , also it is unable to get MyApplication Class. and giving java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: "TargetInvocation Exception" any other details which is provided by gradle log or messages.

"it is unable to get MyApplication Class"  check it is referenced in manifest <application> tag

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.... and it is also showing error Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: healthapp.util.MyApplication$2
                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504)
                                     .........

Comment: Can you please post code of MyApplication class 
as it says "NoClassDefFoundError: healthapp.util.MyApplication$2" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99879/discussion-between-preet-and-jignesh-patel).